# IndexedDB flush to disk on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

I'm facing an issue with IndexedDB on Chrome where I reload my page once the transaction returns a successful write.

Problem is sometimes that data does not reflect after reload. I can solve this by giving a timeout of about 100ms before reload, which leads me to believe that the data is not flushed to disk everytime.

Firexox has an [experimental readwriteflush mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Adding_retrieving_and_removing_data) which ensures data is flushed to disk before returning a success call, but can't seem to find a similar one for Chrome. Any suggestions?

Here's my insert code:

```
const data = {type: type, value: value};

const objectStore = StorageService.db.transaction(['localData'], 'readwrite').objectStore('localData');

// readwriteflush doesn't work in chrome
// const objectStore = StorageService.db.transaction(['localData'], 'readwriteflush').objectStore('localData');

const requestSet = objectStore.put(data);

requestSet.onerror = function (event) {
    alert('Error in saving data locally');
};

requestSet.onsuccess = function (event) {
    console.log('Data was successfully saved locally: ' + type);
    if (callback != undefined) {
        callback();
    }
};
```

The callback has `location.reload = '/';` executed in it (along with some other things), so the page reloads after the onsuccess has been returned.

After the page reloads, I cannot see any data on my IndexedDB storage, both via code and on developer tools. This does not always happen however, I've observed that this happens only when data is larger than usual.

Comment: Please post the code related to storing the data you expect to appear, and the code related to reading the data you expect to find after reload

Comment: @Josh hope this edit helps, please bear with me as this is my first post and let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"success" fired at a request does not indicate that the transaction has committed successfully. The transaction could later fail due to a separate failed request (e.g. a conflicting add call), I/O error, or e.g. power loss.

You need to wait for the "complete" event to be fired at the transaction. Chrome flushes to disk before firing the "complete" event.